# Parsed c-style string into overloaded function

Tags: c++, parsing, overloading

I have a function that takes user input and parses it to the correct overloaded function, I'm not showing all the code just the portions where I'm having problems. When I enter an array into the console as a char C-style string, for example: "55 66 44 33 89"... That array is parsed onto one of the overloaded functions, and in that function, it will sum the array, divide by 5, cast the average to a double, and call the next overloaded function.

I believe the problem is that only the first element "55" is being read, and parsed into the overloaded function. But where does the rest of the input disappear to? The "66 44 33 89", I thought my for loop would capture each element.

```
   //PARSING FUNCTION
        void parseUserInput(char *userInput)
        {
            if (sscanf(userInput, "%i"))
            {
                printf(">> This input should be directed to the << assessGrade(int[]) >> function ...\n");
                assessGrade(atoi(userInput));
            }
        }
    
   //OVERLOADED FUNCTION
        void assessGrade(int array[5])
        {
            int sum = 0;
            int totalDivided = 0;
            
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    sum += array[i];
                    totalDivided = sum / 5;
            
                    assessGrade(atof(totalDivided));
                }
        }
```

Comment: The code does not make sense. `atoi(userInput)` is an `int`. But the function requires an array of `int`. The compiler should be shouting warnings at you.

Comment: @kaylum My thought process was I need to cast the c-style string of chars into an int so that the correct overloaded operator is called. Is this where my problem lies?

Comment: Do you have an overloaded function that takes a single `int`? Because that's what you are calling.

Comment: you do not correctly use scanf, atoi, atof, totalDivided, arrays and probably other stuff as well. Please start with reading documentation at least on the library functions and understand your algorithm. Also, it is strange that you use 'c' functions in a 'c++' program for studying purposes. Please define the language which you want to use.

Comment: @kaylum No I have three overloaded functions, array of ints (which is what I'm trying to call), floating point, and char

Comment: `sscanf(userInput, "%i")` reads exactly one integer from the string.  Then you pass that one integer to the function.  You need to read more than one int from the string  If you know there are 5 numbers then maybe `int array[5]; sscanf(userInput, "%i %i %i %i %i", &array[0], &array[1], &array[2], &array[3], &array[4]);` along with `assessGrade(array);` would work.

Comment: You define no overloaded functions unless there are definitions you are not showing us.

Comment: `sscanf(userInput, "%i")` is undefined behavior, as you are not providing it an `int` to read into, eg: `int val; sscanf(userInput, "%i", &val);` In which case, calling `atoi(userInput)` is redundant since you already have the `int`